# Buying an engagement ring in the US and bringing it to Australia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia

I am from Australia and going on a holiday to LA. I am ordering an engagement ring from the USA and having it shipped to the hotel where I am staying in LA. The ring is not a diamond (it's a moissanite) and its value is around US$1,300 (I am buying it $995 on sale).

Is the ring going to be OK to come back on my fiancés finger through Security and Customs or do we need to pay extra to bring it in back in Australia?

Do I need to declare it coming in or can she just wear it on her finger?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Ente/Duty-Free-concessions you can bring in AU$900 worth of "general goods" (which includes jewelry) without duty.  Since the ring is worth more than that, you (or she) will have to declare it and pay the appropriate customs duty.

The rules for determining how much duty is owed (and other taxes) are typically complicated, so it may be hard to know in advance how much it will cost.  https://www.dutycalculator.com/country-guides/Import-duty-taxes-when-importing-into-Australia/ says that duty rates vary between 0 and 10%, and GST is an additional 10%.

Comment: If you bought it in Australia before the trip and wore it there and back would you have to declare it on the way out?  bring a receipt?  How would they know when you came home to Australia that you bought it in America?

Comment: @BillyC. The question asked what you have to do legally. The question of whether you would be caught if you tried to break the law is a different one.