# Australian immigration long-stay 457 visa - do we need to pay tax on our engagement ring?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australia, import-taxes

Edit: moved this over to the expatriates stackexchange: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11098

Comment: Welcome to Travel StackExchange!  FYI, questions about moving (as opposed to travel) are usually considered to be off-topic here, so this question may end up being closed and/or moved to [Expatriates StackExchange.](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Of possible interest: *[Buying an engagement ring in the US and bringing it to Australia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82549)* and more distantly, *[How do I get an engagement ring past security/customs in an airport without alerting my significant other?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37054)*